# How to configure Eclipse (or any IDE) to compile C++ using Intel compiler in a remote SSH host?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ssh, icc

I'm trying to configure Eclipse in Windows to manage and compile C++ code using Intel C++ compiler (icpc) residing on a remote Linux server via SSH.

The set up is:

Machine A:

- Linux Server.
- Can only access via SSH.
- I do not manage this machine so I do not have admin access.
- Contains Intel C/C++ compiler.

Machine B:

- Windows 10 with Eclipse Neon client.

All I could find with Google was to set up Eclipse to use Intel compiler on local machine, and it requires to have Intel Parallel Studio XE on the local machine (which costs money).

I do not want to install anything else on my local machine (B), if possible.

All I want is to have a decent IDE to make it easier to work with a medium scale C++ project remotely. I'm trying Eclipse because I have some experience with it, but if any IDE with decent C++ intellisense can use a remote Intel C++ compiler via SSH, I'm open to try it.

Can anyone help? Please?

[edit]
Added request for help with any IDE that can accomplish task. It does not need to be Eclipse.

Comment: can you `sshfs`? That would solve most of your problems.
You will see your files from windows, and compile from command line. 
I never really managed to make the remote project work with Eclipse, it's really too messy.

Comment: @dau_sama Accessing the files is not the main problem. The problem is that compilation and execution must happen on the remote Linux server. If there is another IDE solution, I'm open to try it. I just hate using the terminal and remembering compiler flags and creating makefile by hand, and all that. I want to limit my headaches to write code with intellisense, compile with one button, run and debug.

Comment: what about making a build or make script and just launching a command from the terminal? With `C` and `C++` there's no really nice way around that, even if you were running eclipse on the same platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Netbeans? As far I know it's the only IDE offering remote compilation over SSH. Not without issues but usable.